# harvesting fertilized eggs from Tetraodontidae species?

Tags: genomes, ichthyology

I would like to know how easy/difficult it is to harvest fertilized eggs from Tetraodontidae species such as *Tetraodon nigroviridis* or *Takifugu rubripes* compared to zebrafish? Ultimately, I would like to know how much material would be obtainable from Tetraodontidae eggs to extract DNA from the nuclei.

I know zebrafish lay lots of eggs, and other model fish species like medaka lay much fewer of them, but I couldn't find any information about *Tetraodon nigroviridis* or *Takifugu rubripes* after some googling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For DNA extraction, you would need only a few eggs. PCR would then give you all the copies of your target gene(s). A quick Google Scholar search on *Takifugu* fecundity revealed a paper by [Yang and Chen (2008)](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1439-0426.2008.01071.x/abstract). They found that *T. obscurus* produced an average of 320.8 oocytes mg$^{-1}$ ovary wet weight. In comparison, *T. ocellatus* produced 125.2 oocytes mg$^{-1}$ ovary wet weight. *Takifugu rupripes* and other species are likely in a similar range, which is plenty of tissue for DNA. [Kusakabe (1962)](http://ci.nii.ac.jp/naid/10016123524/) published on the fecundity of *T. rubripes* but the paper is in Japanese and is not readily available to me.

**Beware:** *T. rubripes* ovaries are [highly toxic](http://fishbase.org/summary/Takifugu-rubripes.html). Why not use other tissue instead?